# Properly meshing a metaball

Tags: mesh

I am new to metaballs and I want to mesh a metaball, so that I can export it. For a simple test I just added a metaball to a cube. This is how I created my strange metaball:

1. Add a cube
2. Add a metaball
3. Select the metaball and then while holding shift select the cube
4. Ctrl P to `parent to object`
5. Go to the `Cube settings > Instancing > Faces`

After looking up how mesh it I went under `Object > Convert To > Mesh from Curve/Meta`. This creates a mesh but isn't what I really want.

I don't know if I did something wrong, I just followed a tutorial on how to use metaballs. Here is the produced mesh:

[image]

But I just want a mesh that looks like the unmeshed metaball:

[image]

Here is my blend file:

[image]

Comment: If I create some connecting meta-balls and Convert them to a mesh, I get a single mesh without seams. The seams in your image are really strange, and i don't know how to (or can't) recreate them. If you select your metaball-converted-to-mesh and go into Edit Mode and press P and choose By Loose Parts, do you get multiple objects? What else can you tell about how you made this mesh? And why (I assume) did you parent the meta-balls to a cube? In any case, I think a more detailed step by step explanation of how the mesh was made can help figure out what went wrong.

Comment: I added an instruction and also my blend file. I can't really do anything with the mesh in edit mode, I don't see vertices or anything. I also can't separate them. I used a cube because I noticed this weird behavior in an other more complex mesh and want to eliminate as many sources of error as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'm starting to understand what is going on. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you parented the meta-ball to the cube to change it to the desired shape.

A mesh with this shape is inside the weird thing with the seams.

I converted your meta-ball in the file to a mesh. Then selected it and removed it as a child from the cube. 3D viewport > Object > Parent > Clear Parent (or press Alt+P). The thing with the seams disappears, and then i'm left with the mesh I believe you want.

Since this was, as you described it, a simple test, I hope (but am unable to tell if) it also works in a more complicated scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that is working also with the more complex model

Answer (score 0):

[image]maybe with Boolean modifier and remesh modifier can achieve what you want without work with metaballs...
add the boolean and set it union with and in the object select the other obj
after add a remesh modifier and play with it

Comment: Can you be a bit more detailed? There aren't modifiers for metaballs

Comment: it is not metaballs but could do similar things [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=EXRSeBAy" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/EXRSeBAy/)